# How to speed up my VBA Script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a single sheet with 7800 Rows by 2382 columns approx. (19.5Million Cells)

Out of this I have 22 x columns I am actually interest in, which have 5 x digit numbers scatted within them.

Essentially if a number in the first of the columns is then found in any of the other 21 x columns I want to turn the relevant rows, columns A cell interior RED.

I have got this working, I believe with the attached code, but it takes around 3 x hours to run.

I would like to ask firstly, is this a reasonable amount of time (3 x Hours) with the size of the spreadsheet?

If you would expect the routine to be a lot quicker, I would really appreciate your guidance on how it should be scripted.

```
Sub FindMatch()


Dim rng_1 As Range
Dim rng_2 As Range
Dim rng_3 As Range
Dim rng_4 As Range
Dim rng_5 As Range
Dim rng_6 As Range
Dim rng_7 As Range
Dim rng_8 As Range
Dim rng_9 As Range
Dim rng_10 As Range
Dim rng_11 As Range
Dim rng_12 As Range
Dim rng_13 As Range
Dim rng_14 As Range
Dim rng_15 As Range
Dim rng_16 As Range
Dim rng_17 As Range
Dim rng_18 As Range
Dim rng_19 As Range
Dim rng_20 As Range
Dim rng_21 As Range
Dim rng_22 As Range



Dim rngRef_1 As Range
Dim rngRef_2 As Range
Dim rngRef_3 As Range
Dim rngRef_4 As Range
Dim rngRef_5 As Range
Dim rngRef_6 As Range
Dim rngRef_7 As Range
Dim rngRef_8 As Range
Dim rngRef_9 As Range
Dim rngRef_10 As Range
Dim rngRef_11 As Range
Dim rngRef_12 As Range
Dim rngRef_13 As Range
Dim rngRef_14 As Range
Dim rngRef_15 As Range
Dim rngRef_16 As Range
Dim rngRef_17 As Range
Dim rngRef_18 As Range
Dim rngRef_19 As Range
Dim rngRef_20 As Range
Dim rngRef_21 As Range
Dim rngRef_22 As Range


Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng_1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$DQ$2:$DQ$8000")
Set rng_2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$GW$2:$GW$8000")
Set rng_3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$KC$2:$KC$8000")
Set rng_4 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$NI$2:$NI$8000")
Set rng_5 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$QO$2:$QO$8000")
Set rng_6 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$TU$2:$TU$8000")
Set rng_7 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$XA$2:$XA$8000")
Set rng_8 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$AAG$2:$AAG$8000")
Set rng_9 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$ADM$2:$ADM$8000")
Set rng_10 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$AGS$2:$AGS$8000")
Set rng_11 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$AJY$2:$AJY$8000")
Set rng_12 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$ANE$2:$ANE$8000")
Set rng_13 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$AQK$2:$AQK$8000")
Set rng_14 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$ATQ$2:$ATQ$8000")
Set rng_15 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$AWW$2:$AWW$8000")
Set rng_16 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BAC$2:$BAC$8000")
Set rng_17 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BDI$2:$BDI$8000")
Set rng_18 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BGO$2:$BGO$8000")
Set rng_19 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BJU$2:$BJU$8000")
Set rng_20 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BNA$2:$BNA$8000")
Set rng_21 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BQG$2:$BQG$8000")
Set rng_22 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$BTM$2:$BTM$8000")







Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_2 In rng_2
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_2.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_3 In rng_3
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_3.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_4 In rng_4
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_4.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next


Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_5 In rng_5
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_5.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_6 In rng_6
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_6.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_7 In rng_7
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_7.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next




Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_8 In rng_8
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_8.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_9 In rng_9
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_9.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_10 In rng_10
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_10.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next


Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_11 In rng_11
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_11.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_12 In rng_12
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_12.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_13 In rng_13
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_13.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next

Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_14 In rng_14
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_14.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next


Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_15 In rng_15
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_15.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_16 In rng_16
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_16.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_17 In rng_17
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_17.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next




Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_18 In rng_18
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_18.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_19 In rng_19
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_19.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_20 In rng_20
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_20.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next


Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_21 In rng_21
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_21.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------
 For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   For Each rngRef_22 In rng_22
     If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
       If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_22.Value Then

        rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

       End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
Rem -----------------------------------------------------



Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You have >19M cells and <100k numbers. Why not find all 5-digit-numbers first and then turn just those in column A red, that you found?

Comment: Hi Alex, How would you do that, I can't see an approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things faster you can change your code

```
For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
    For Each rngRef_2 In rng_2
        If rngRef_1.Value <> "" Then
            If rngRef_1.Value = rngRef_2.Value Then
                rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

to

```
For Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng_2, rngRef_1.Value) > 0 Then _
   rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
```

Similarly for others. This avoids looping and checks for the duplicate using the `CountIf` Formula.

**NOTE**: To make your existing code faster without using the above suggested method, add `Exit For` right after `rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`. After a match is found, no point in checking further. Similarly for the others.

**Further Optimization**: I spent some time reading your code and I noticed something. Your code consists of **283 lines** which can be reduced to just **53 lines** :)

The trick is to identify a pattern in your code. Your compare range starts from Col `DQ` and goes up till column `BTM` The difference between each range is `84` columns i.e

```
GW = 205
NI = 373

and so on...

BTM = 1885
```

So all we have to do now is construct the next range in a loop rather than predefining it. Also instead of coloring the cell in a loop we are doing it outside the loop. This will also speed things up :)

**New Code (Untested)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindMatch()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngRef As Range, aCell As Range, colorMyRange As Range
    Dim nCalc As Long, i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Application
        nCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("$DQ$2:$DQ$8000")

        For i = 205 To 1885 Step 84
            Set rngRef = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(8000, i))

            For Each aCell In rng
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngRef, aCell.Value) > 0 Then
                    If colorMyRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set colorMyRange = aCell.Offset(0, -120)
                    Else
                        Set colorMyRange = Union(colorMyRange, aCell.Offset(0, -120))
                    End If
                End If

            Next

            If Not colorMyRange Is Nothing Then
                colorMyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Set colorMyRange = Nothing
            End If
        Next i
    End With

LetsContinue:

    With Application
        .Calculation = nCalc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, I will shortly amend the code and give it a try.

Comment: @user3274198: I just fixed a typo. You may want to refresh the page

Comment: Also your code can be reduced to 1/10 of what it is right now :)

Comment: Hi Siddarth, Pure Genius it works like lightning, thank you so much. Andrew, Also just so I understand the Syntax change for the second For Each group, Do I change the Countif(rng_2 to Countif(rng_3? Is that the only change?

Comment: Wait I am updating the post to show how you can intelligently cut your original colde to 1/10... gimme 10 mins

Comment: @user3274198: BTW who is Andrew? :D

Comment: +1 `Your code consists of 283 lines which can be reduced to just 53 lines :)`

Comment: An aussie, Comms Engineer, trying to assist team mates with some non existent VBA Skills :-). I will try very shortly, how about yourself Siddharth? Who is Siddarth?

Comment: `Who is Siddarth?` @user3274198: If my memory is not failing me "Siddharth" is my name :D

Comment: @user3274198: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Hi Siddarth, sorry to bother you, one thing I was hoping it would do is if it finds a match for the first column $DQ$2:$DQ$8000.Is it would change the Column A cell to red, which is what it does. but it doesn't Change the other 21 x columns Column A to RED if it gets a match on $DQ$2:$DQ$8000. Is this a big change?

Comment: @user3274198: Do you want to color the cells in Col GW-BTW Red as well?

Comment: Hi Siddarth, What I am trying to do is get a visual reference for any row that has a duplicate Number in those 22 columns. I was using column A as the place for this as you could readily see if a row your working on has a duplicate. Your Question is about actually identifying the cells which are duplicates and turning them a colour as Well, yes that would definitely be very useful. But I am mindful of asking to much.

Comment: @user3274198: The problem with your request is that you will then have to loop through individual ranges and this will increase the code running time drastically.

Comment: Would your original code perform, this function all but run a little slowerFor Each rngRef_1 In rng_1
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng_2, rngRef_1.Value) > 0 Then _
   rngRef_1.Offset(0, -120).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next

Comment: Sorry bad cut and paste. If I had the 22 x instances of the For Each statement as the first approach on this?

Comment: @user3274198 Yes you can do it but it is the same as your original code then. I don't think there would be much of a time difference. But anyways give it a try :)